# Merge separate polygons inside of a single JSON that do NOT share a boundary

Tags: qgis, polygon, json, polygon-creation, multi-polygon

I am trying to see if there is a way to merge/connect polygons that do not share a boundary with one another. As you can see from the imagine, these are two polygons that I'm looking to connect, if possible.

[image]

So far, I've been working inside of QGIS but haven't had any success.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to show what you envision the result this process would be.

Comment: Use the single to multi part tool